# Mock server response

Tags: java, google-api, integration-testing, mockserver

I have a web app that allows clients to log in using social providers (Google / Facebook). I would like to write integration tests that check my implementation in the case of a successful / unsuccessful response from the provider. For that, I need to mock the server response from the provider (e.g. Google).

Considering that my API endpoint is **/social_login**, the code which will be eventually reached makes a request to the Google endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo. I want the response from the later to be mocked, so that my code is independent of the Google Api. Is there a way I could achieve this?

My implementation is done in Java.

Comment: There's a similar question but for Spring specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550098/mock-external-server-during-integration-testing-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to provide an integration test, but that you want your code to be independent of the service. I'm not sure it's definitely an integration test that you're looking for but hopefully we can provide some useful feedback or drive out some extra info.

I assume the logic that acts upon the response is separate from the client that communicates with the service. In which case it should be straightforward to provide a mock of the client to your own application.

Alternatively if you are using the actual client, then the URLs it hits could be set using a property file which could be different for tests versus live.